# How to create files and respective folders after reading files from a directory randomly

Tags: java, file

I want to read 10% of the files from a directory which contains sub-directories and want to write files as in respective sub-directories.I am currently able to read 10% random files using random method and write them in a folder but the code doesn't work for sub-directories.
My code is:

```
    '

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;


public class CreateSampleDocuments
{
    String text="";
    String str="";
    Map<Integer, File> selection = new HashMap<Integer, File>(1000);
    public void readSampleFiles(File files[])throws IOException
    {
        while (selection.size() <= files.length/5) 
        {
            int value = (int)Math.round(Math.random() * files.length);
            if (!selection.containsKey(value)) 
            {
                selection.put(value, files[value]);
            }
        }
        for (File file : selection.values())
        {
            if(file.isFile())
            {
            String name = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter("/home/gauge/Documents/Docs/Misc"+"/"+name);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while((text=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                pw.write(text+"\n");
                pw.flush();
            }
            //System.out.println(file);
            }
            else if(file.isDirectory())
            {

            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException 
    {
        File files[] = new File("/home/gauge/Documents/Docs/Filtered Documents/Orissa/TextFiles/Year1952").listFiles();
        CreateSampleDocuments d=new CreateSampleDocuments();
        d.readSampleFiles(files);
    }
}
```

'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is 100% percent what you need (Question is not very clear) but I think you could make your code a little bit clearer.

```
    try {
        List<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get("path")).filter(path -> Files.isRegularFile(path)).collect(Collectors.toList());            
        int ten_percent = files.size()/10;          
        Collections.shuffle(files); //Randomize         
        files.stream().limit(ten_percent).forEach(source -> copyFile(source, Paths.get("newPAth").resolve(UUID.randomUUID().toString())));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and the copyFile method (Just to get rid of the Exception in the forEach):

```
private void copyFile(Path source, Path dest) {
    try {
        Files.copy(source, dest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This should now copy 10% of your files into the folder.

If you need to copy complete Directories, don't use the filte in the first stream and use this method:

```
private void copyDirectory(final Path sourcePath, final Path targetPath) throws IOException {
    Files.walkFileTree(sourcePath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(final Path dir, final BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            Files.createDirectories(targetPath.resolve(sourcePath.relativize(dir)));
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(final Path file, final BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            Files.copy(file, targetPath.resolve(sourcePath.relativize(file)));
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As a matter of good practice, that catch block should contain `throw new RuntimeException(e);`, instead of just printing the stack trace.  Unless the software really doesn't care whether a file copy succeeded, which I find unlikely.

Comment: Yes, you Are of course right. Left this out, because thats his decision what to do with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using listfiles use list you will get both files and folder.
For all files in the String array call your readSampleFiles method. For each folder in the string array redo the same as you did in main recurssively.